# How to set the return value of a method to the result of a for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, methods, return

Given a string str, and a number num, I need to use a loop to get the string to be repeated num times. It's set up as a method, and the return value should be the new string, which is the original string repeated however many times. I don't know how to "set" the result of the string being repeated x times as the return value for the method.

```
public String repeatText(String strg, int num)
{   
    String answer; 
        for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
           System.out.print(strg);
         //how to I set the output of this for loop 
        //as answer, which will then
       //be set as the return value?
    }


    return answer;
```

}

I get an error that answer variable has not been initiated. I don't know how to initiate it/set it as what I get out of the for loop running its course.

Comment: Basically, you want to append several times the string strg+" " to the String answer ? Did you try `concat()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize the `answer` to empty string, as:

```
public String repeatText(String strg, int num) {
    // initialize answer to empty string
    String answer = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        // append strg to answer
        answer += strg;
    }
    return answer;
}
```